# When does nginx $upstream_response_time start/stop specifically

Tags: performance, nginx, query-performance

Does anyone know when, specifically, the clock for `$upstream_response_time` begins and ends?

The documentation seems a bit vague:

> keeps time spent on receiving the response from the upstream server; the time is kept in seconds with millisecond resolution. Times of several responses are separated by commas and colons like addresses in the $upstream_addr variable.

There is also an `$upstream_header_time` value, which adds more confusion.

1. I assume `$upstream_connect_time` stops once the connection is established, but **before** it is accepted upstream?
2. After this what does `$upstream_response_time` include?

   - Time spent waiting for upstream to accept?
   - Time spent sending the request?
   - Time spent sending the response header?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more specific definition is in their [blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-logging-for-application-performance-monitoring/).

> **$request_time** – Full request time, starting when NGINX reads the first
> byte from the client and ending when NGINX sends the last byte of the
> response body
>
> **$upstream_connect_time** – Time spent establishing a
> connection with an upstream server
>
> **$upstream_header_time** – Time
> between establishing a connection to an upstream server and receiving
> the first byte of the response header
>
> **$upstream_response_time** – Time
> between establishing a connection to an upstream server and receiving
> the last byte of the response body

So

- `$upstream_header_time` is included in `$upstream_response_time`.
- Time spent connecting to upstream is not included in both of them.
- Time spent sending response to client is not included in both of them.

Answer (score 11):

I've investigated and debug the behavior around this, and it turned out as follows:

|  | start time | end time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $upstream_connect_time | before Nginx establishes TCP connection with upstream server | before Nginx sends HTTP request to upstream server |
| $upstream_header_time | before Nginx establishes TCP connection with upstream server | after Nginx receives and processes headers in HTTP response from upstream server |
| $upstream_response_time | before Nginx establishes TCP connection with upstream server | after Nginx receives and processes HTTP response from upstream server |

### source code

I'll explain how values are different between $upstream_connect_time and $upstream_response_time, as it's what I was primarily interested in.

The value of `u->state->connect_time`, which represents $upstream_connect_time in millisecond, is ingested in the following section: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/3334585539168947650a37d74dd32973ab451d70/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c#L2073

```c
    if (u->state->connect_time == (ngx_msec_t) -1) {
        u->state->connect_time = ngx_current_msec - u->start_time;
    }
```

Whereas the value of `u->state->response_time`, which represents $upstream_response_time in millisecond, is set in the following section: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/3334585539168947650a37d74dd32973ab451d70/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c#L4432

```c
    if (u->state && u->state->response_time == (ngx_msec_t) -1) {
        u->state->response_time = ngx_current_msec - u->start_time;
```

You can notice that both of values are calculated based on `u->start_time`, which is the time just before the connection is established, defined in https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/3334585539168947650a37d74dd32973ab451d70/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c#L1533
(note that `ngx_event_connect_peer` is a function to establish TCP connection between nginx workerprocesses and upstream servers).

Therefore, both values include the time taken to establish the TCP connection. You can check this by doing a live debug with, for example,  gdbserver.